# UXpin overseas user testing and Usability Testing Software

Tags: usability-testing, user-centered-design

I work for a company and we build all of our applications in house. We are world wide and so I have been trying to push our user testing over seas. All of my prototypes are developed in UXpin. I thought I found the perfect application, loop11.com, to do the oversea user testing. I set up all my test, but it would not load UXpin within the site. 
After a lot of emailing back and fourth they say I need to get a snippet of java from UXpin to insert into my prototypes to make it work. I am currently working on this step, but am starting to get into a time crunch with this testing.

I was wondering if anyone had done any overseas user testing and how they accomplished this. I am mostly working with China so there is 12 hours difference. I am not concerned about video.. most video testing I have seen makes you install a plugin. There is a large language barrier so I feel like the least amount of steps to prep for this test the better. 
What I really liked about Loop11 was they allowed you to set up scenario testing and then review the data by heat maps, pass fail criteria, and path analysis.

I am really looking for any feedback on how to accomplish this testing, or really how to even start this testing.

Any feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

1. Export your UXpin prototype to HTML. (https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/export-prototype-to-html-pdf/)
2. Now that you have the HTML version, include your loop11 snippet into the prototype
3. Upload this onto a server.
4. Send your users link to the uploaded prototype